# Spring hibernate error about lazy loading

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm just a spring + hibernate beginner. I'm doing a simple project and I set up eveything for transactions, a simple service, a simple dao and all the annotated beans.

Using list works, I can list the objects and their properties, using a Criteria query. But if I try to load an object with:

```
Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Ordine res = (Ordine) sess.load(Ordine.class, id);
return res;
```

the query seems to work fine, but I get a nasty exception when the View tries to read a property (a string):

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

I even noticed this is the startup logs:

> INFO: Bean 'mySessionFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

What does all this mean?

Answer (score 4):

You have a few choises the way I see it

- Force your object to not be loaded lazily (e.g., set `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` on your persistence annotations).
- [OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://pieno.be/content/2010/opensessioninviewinterceptor-example-spring-3-web-mvc)
- Invoke the methods of your routine in data layer (to load the values) before invoking them in your view.

[Edit] This does not at all seem to work as I initially suggested.

- Add [transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained). Annotate your controller routine using `@Transactional`.

Comment: *Annotate your controller routine using `@Transactional`* Does that work? The view is beyond the controller's scope, isn't it?

Comment: I tried it out once, and if I remember correctly it behaved well (my memory might be hazy though). This of course assumes you have all spring-configuration needed for transaction scanning.

Comment: This answer is right, minus the @Transactional per Sean's comment.

Comment: I tried to put FetchType.Eager, no success. I put the OpenSessionInViewIntercepto.... nothing.

Comment: I tried both and can verify that they work. Can you illustrate with more code what you're doing? E.g., @OneToMany(..., fetch=...) ? Also, when using OSIV you should place it in the same appcontext as your controller definitions, see e.g. [this](http://72miles.com/blog/spring-opensessioninviewinterceptor-opensessioninviewfilter-examples/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the [`OpenSessionInViewFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sean,

Johan's suggestion about setting fetch=FetType.EAGER is your simplest solution.  You should be careful using this solution, though.  Sometimes you can solve your problem by modifying your dao query to do a left join fetch on the related entity that you're interested in. eg:

```
Query q = this.em.createQuery("select x from PrimaryEntity x \n"
+ "left join fetch x.secondaryEntityField \n "
+ "where x.selectionProperty = :selection");
```

Comment: Uhm, Sean did not ask the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

org.hibernate.Hibernate -class has some handy static utility methods, for example see [Hibernate.initialize](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize%28java.lang.Object%29). You still need an open session for it though. The easiest ways are probably using OpenSessionInViewFilter, setting fetch-types to eager or modifying the query to load the lazy-relations, as suggested in the other answers.